# Varying filling colour in Gnuplot according to certain palette

Tags: gnuplot, fill

I want to fill a number of closed curves using Gnuplot. This is the result I get so far.

[image]

Not bad. I have used this code:

```
plot \
'fort.40' u 1:2 smooth bezier w filledcurves lt 1 lc 4 lw 3 t 't=100 s' ,\
'fort.30' u 1:2 smooth bezier w filledcurves lt 1 lc 3 lw 3 t 't=20 s' ,\
'fort.20' u 1:2 smooth bezier w filledcurves lt 1 lc 2 lw 3 t 't=1 s' ,\
'fort.10' u 1:2 smooth bezier w filledcurves lt 1 lc 1 lw 3 t 't=0'
```

However, what I really want is to plot like one hundred of such curves (for physicists, what I want is to illustrate the temporal evolution of a circle in the phase space of something like a double pendulum). Each closed curve is stored as two columns with the coordinates of the curve in a different ASCII file. As you see, I have achieved the figure above with four different filling colours set by hand. But now I would like to generalise it to have a smooth transition of colours, following certain palette. The idea is that the colour gives an hint about the third dimension implicit in the figure: time.

Do you know if it is possible at all to use a filling colour that follows certain palette, instead of a fixed colour? In the worst case, I could define 100 filling styles (I create the code within a shell script, so it is relatively easy to automatise the process), but still I do not know whether it is possible to assign a colour based on a palette, instead of a colour giving by hand.

EDIT: Thanks to the excellent answer by @Christoph, this is the final output. I leave it here just to illustrate how powerfull Gnuplot can be.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filledcurves` plotting style doesn't support `lc palette` or `lc [rgb] variable`, which is what one would use to color lines.

For `filledcurves` you can use `lc palette frac <value>`, where `<value>` is a number in the range `[0:1]` which specifies the fractional position in the current palette, where the color is taken from. That requires you to know the number of files you are plotting:

```
set style fill solid noborder
plot \
'fort.40' u 1:2 smooth bezier w filledcurves lc palette frac 1 t 't=100 s' ,\
'fort.30' u 1:2 smooth bezier w filledcurves lc palette frac 0.6667 t 't=20 s' ,\
'fort.20' u 1:2 smooth bezier w filledcurves lc palette frac 0.3333 t 't=1 s' ,\
'fort.10' u 1:2 smooth bezier w filledcurves lc palette frac 0 t 't=0'
```

To iterate over the files you could use

```
files = 'fort.40 fort.30 fort.20 fort.10'
times = '100     20      1       0'
N = words(files)

set style fill solid noborder
plot for [i=1:words(files)] word(files, i) u 1:2 smooth bezier with filledcurves lc palette frac (N-i)/(N-1.0) t sprintf('t=%s s', word(times, i)
```

Comment: Not only a very precise answer, but I could learn a couple of new things and you were even faster answering than I was writing the question. I'll give it a try before marking it as answered, but I'm pretty sure it will work. Thanks.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, I have edited the question to add the final output. I hope this is not against the rules of the web. Pretty neat, although the shading has ugly artefacts that I would like to remove. But I guess this is topic for another question.